# How could I resume my own python configuration after quiting anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Before installing anaconda, I have my own python configurations:

> $ python
>   Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
>   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   ...

After installing anaconda, however, without creating a new environment, my default environment is still changed:

> $ python
>   Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
>   [GCC 7.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   ...

How could I use my own 3.5.2 python environment when not activating the anaconda python environment ?

Comment: check the env variable "path", while installation anaconda has added path of python 3.7 to env variable, now if you want to use the older version either use the full path of the older python or change the path variable.

Comment: @Sach So you mean I have no way to use my original configurations if I want to switch between different anaconda environments ?

Comment: you have a way, you can directly use the full python path of old installation.